# How to read JSON data from external URL and display it in a node

Tags: nodes, uri

I want to read json data from external url and display those data in a node. After that I would like to add filters in the result using views. I have created a view using external url(query settings) and display result in a block.. But I cant add filters for that. How to add Filters for that data.. I am new to this.. Please help me..

Comment: Views filter results by updating SQL statement. That is probably the reason why they don't work. If your json can be filtered using parameters then maybe you can write a custom view filter. Otherwise you will need to filter using JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

If the data does not have to be live and can be fetched / updated every x number of minutes, then I suggest you create a task with scheduler which loads the remote data into a local database table at a specified interval (`drupal_json_decode` can help converting the JSON string into an array that can be inserted in the database). After you do that you would be able to adopt that table into Drupal & Views using the [Data module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data). This would make the data available as a view with sort handlers and filters, like any other view. Otherwise, to handle live data I would suggest integrating Angular JS to retrieve the remote JSON and to filter the results. [NgApp module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ngapp) can help you in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

There could be options like [Web Service Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsdata) and [External Entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/external_entities).